# flutter input text not working on android

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, textfield

My Flutter app does not input text in the `TextField` in the `Android Emulator`. But it works well on the IOS simulator

```
class GeneralRegistration extends StatelessWidget {
  final int lengthLimitingTextInputFormatter;
  final String phoneNumberHint;
  final String phoneNumberPrefix;
  const GeneralRegistration({
    super.key,
    required this.lengthLimitingTextInputFormatter,
    required this.phoneNumberHint,
    required this.phoneNumberPrefix,
    
  });

    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        final phone = TextEditingController();
    
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            appBar: Utils().appBar(context),
            body: Container(
                         child: TextField(
                            inputFormatters: [
                              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                  lengthLimitingTextInputFormatter)
                            ],
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              if (value.length ==
                                  lengthLimitingTextInputFormatter) {
                                setState(() {});
                              }
                            },
                            controller: phone,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 40,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: phoneNumberHint,
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade600, fontSize: 20),
                                prefix: Text(
                                  phoneNumberPrefix,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                suffixIcon: phone.text.length ==
                                        lengthLimitingTextInputFormatter
                                    ? const Icon(
                                        Icons.done,
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        size: 40,
                                      )
                                    : null),
                          ),
                        ),
          );
        });
      }
    }
```

Can someone help, please? This same code worked on a different app, but doesn't seem to work here.